# Is it possible in git to push submodule defined as relative path to bare?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I got this scenario:

1. I created a Git repository.

   $ git init
2. Cloned an external repository in a sub directory. (using git-hg in my case)

   $ git hg clone lib remote_uri
3. Added the the cloned library as submodule

   $ git submodule add lib ./lib
4. Then I commited the changes

   $ git commit -am "added lib"

After this procedure, if I `git clone` this repo and `git submodule init/update` the new one, I get the repo and the lib.

Anyway, If I try to push the repo to a bare one, and clone from the bare to another place, the new one crashes trying to get the lib.
I tried to `git submodule init` in the bare, but the command doesn't work if you doesn't have a working copy.

Someone got any idea what can be done?

** Update **
Here is an example without the hg.

```
This is a way to reproduce it.
/tmp$ git clone https://github.com/gitster/git.git
/tmp$ cd git/
/tmp/git [master]$ git clone https://github.com/gitster/git.git gitrepo
/tmp/git [master]$ git submodule add ./gitrepo
/tmp/git [master]$ git commit -am "added repo"
/tmp$ cd ..
/tmp$ git clone --bare git  gitbare
/tmp$ git clone  gitbare gittest
/tmp$ cd gittest/
/tmp/gittest [master]$ git submodule init
Submodule 'gitrepo' (/tmp/gitbare/gitrepo) registered for path 'gitrepo'
/tmp/gittest [master]$ git submodule update
fatal: repository '/tmp/gitbare/gitrepo' does not exist
Clone of '/tmp/gitbare/gitrepo' into submodule path 'gitrepo' failed
```

Comment: If you've done what you say, it should be trying to clone the submodule on initialization from wherever you originally cloned it from, just like your local clone of the parent project does. Have you actually pushed the commit in question to the bare repo? When you clone it, do you see that commit in the history? Where does it try to clone the submodule from? Is it the correct place? What's the error? (What do you mean, "crashes"?)

Comment: It actually tries to clone form the bare/lib but bare doesnt have a lib, apparently because bare doesn't have a working copy and the lib repo lives in the working copy.

Comment: I'm not asking about the error when you try to run `submodule init` in the bare repo - that will never work. I'm asking about "clone from the bare to another place, the new one crashes trying to get the lib".

Comment: Added how to reproduce it and the error in the Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be expecting the impossible. Submodules are repositories in their own right, and to be able to clone them from anywhere, there has to be an accessible repository for them, just like there does for the parent repository. You've added a submodule with no public URL configuration. Git isn't going to be able to magically fetch it out of the version you stuck in that original repository.

You need to update the URL for the submodule to something that'll be accessible from wherever you want to clone it from. You should host it in the same way that you do your parent repository, whether that's on a single machine, on a single network, or on GitHub.

And by the way, your reproduction instructions are not the same as your actual use case. In the toy case you've posted, all you have to do is correctly add the submodule, using the public URL:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/gitster/git.git gitrepo
```

and everything will work fine. If you host the thing that you're trying to add as a submodule in a similar way, then the appropriate version of this command will work for you.

Comment: Yes, I know the toy case can be solved that way, but it reproduces the same error that the one in the mercurial case.
I will go with the remote repository procedure. Just wanted to know if someone had found some work around this, it doesn't only happen to people using git-hg but those using git-svn or cvs too.

Comment: @dvicino: It happens to anyone who puts a submodule in an entirely local repository, then expects it to be available elsewhere... It would happen if you just ran `git init` and created a repository in the subdirectory. What I was trying to make clear is that there can't be a "workaround".

Answer (score 0):

Set the URL for the submodule to point to where the submodule repo exists. Don't call submodule init after that as it will reset it to the place that doesn't have it.

Comment: So far the repo is only in my machine. I'm pulling from a non-git repo, so i can't share that uri using the .gitmodule

Comment: You can introduce an intermediate repo so you can have just git for this purpose.